# When i try to store my entity using jdo, I am getting this error.. how to solve this

Tags: java, database, jsp, servlets, jdo

I am using GAE datastore. When I store data using `pm.makePersistent(emp)`, I am getting this error.

> The class `com.jdo.JDOServlet` is not persistable. This means that it
>   either hasn't been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file
>   is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or
>   the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.

How to solve this?

Comment: looks like a problem with redeployment of the enhanced version of the file. can you build it once again, redeploy and check.

Comment: i checked so many times. but its not working. i deleted entire kind and entities. Even though its showing this same error. i don't know why...

Comment: why are you passing a "JDOServlet" object to makePersistent (either directly, or as a field in a persistable object) ?